# A function bounded away from zero

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Using this definition:
A function $f: [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is *bounded away from zero* on $[a,b]$ if there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $f(x) > \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$, or $f(x)<-\epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

I am trying to prove the following statement: 
Prove that a continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that does not vanish on the interval $[a,b]$ is bounded away from zero on $[a,b]$.

I'm confused on how to start this proof. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Outline:

- Let $g(x)=|f(x)|$.$\\[4pt]$

  Then $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. (why?)$\\[4pt]$

  It follows that $g$ achieves an absolute minimum, $m$ say, on $[a,b]$. (why?)$\\[4pt]$

  Necessarily $m \ge 0$. (why?)$\\[4pt]$

  But we can't have $m=0$. (why?)$\\[4pt]$

  Choose $\epsilon$ with $0 < \epsilon < m$

  Using that choice of $\epsilon$, it follows that $f$ is bounded away from zero (why?)$\\[4pt]$

Comment: Very instructive answer. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more basic way of doing it. Suppose $f$ does not vanish on $[a,b]$. That is $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. Now, suppose $f$ is not bounded away from $0$. Then, for every $\varepsilon > 0$ we have $x_{\varepsilon} \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x_{\varepsilon})<\varepsilon$. Take this sequence of $(x_{\varepsilon})$ then $f(x_{\varepsilon}) \to 0$ as $\varepsilon \to 0$. Since $[a,b]$ is a closed interval there now must be $x \in [a,b]$ such that $f(x)=0$. A contradiction. Thus, $f$ must be bounded away from $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $[a,b]$ is a compact interval,  $f([a,b])$ is a closed interval $[u,v]$ $(f([a,b])$ is closed since the image of a compact set by a continuous map is closed, it is an interval since the image of an interval by a continuous map is an interval), we cannot have $u<0$ and $v>0$, since $0$ is not in the image, we deduce that $u>0$ or $v<0$.

Comment: You mean, $[a, b]$ is a compact set. Also, I think you mixed up $u, v$ and $c, d$

Answer (score 0):

As $g\colon x\mapsto \frac1x$ is continuous on its domain $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, the composition $x\mapsto g(f(x))$ is continuous, hence bounded on the compact interval $[a,b]$. Say, $|g(f(x))|<M$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Then with $\epsilon:=\frac 1M$,we have $|f(x)|>\epsilon$ for all $x\in[a,b]$.